# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (line 36, file "Code.gs"

Tags: javascript, referenceerror, unexpected-token

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" async defer></script>
gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "1018259411070-9ra6d5kea2tsk2ofblkt4vatjo1b7rba.apps.googleusercontent.com"});


 });
```

I am trying to format a JSON object with Google Sheets and it wont allow me till this is fixed. I tried deleting the <script scr sentence, but then the response is "ReferenceError: gapi is not defined (line 37, file "Code")." Also is there any shortcut into reversing the order of the items in my JSON object. Sorry if this isn't detailed enough I am new to coding and using API's. Just let me know if you need more information!

Comment: `<script src="https:....` should be in the html part not in the js file or within another `<script>` tag